# Error when creating PDF files in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, dompdf

I followed [these](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_PDF_views) instructions exactly (a few times now). When I add format=pdf to the end of my URL query string as instructed, I get this error:

```
500 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: article, pdf, contentView
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. This is definitely a Joomla issue, as I am able to create PDF's using the DOMPDF library on it's own.

I am using Joomla 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

You need a view with in the following file:

`view.pdf.php`

Alternatively, but not as clean, you can pack everything inside a method in a controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I created this file by copying view.html.php and renaming, exactly as instructed in the documentation. http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_PDF_views

I was thinking of going the controller method if I can't get this working. Thanks.